# pull an item from an array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I can shift an item from an array by using array_pop or array_shift, but this works for the beginning or the ending of a string. I'm looking to pull an item from an array by it's key, so:

```
$a = [
  'first' => '1st',
  'second' => '2nd',
  'third' => '3rd'
];

$item = pull_by_key( $a, 'second' );
echo $item;
```

the output would be (and $item would be set to) `2nd` and the resulting array should be:

```
[ 'first' => '1st', 'third' => '3rd' ]
```

I can do this with a custom function:

```
function pull_by_key( &$array, $key ){
   $retval = $array[$key];
   unset( $array[$key] );
   return $retval;
}
```

... but I was wondering if there was a function that did this. I couldn't find anything.

So, to make it clear: I don't just want to remove an item with unset, I want to pull the item from the array. So an `array_pop` or `array_shift`, but not the first or last item from an array, but the item by it's key.

Comment: Not a duplicate... it's not removing a specific element from an array, it's pulling it from an array, take a look at the function, it's pulling the item (so I know it's content) and THEN removing it from the array... read the question before you vote to close it, please

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, sorry, but "but I was wondering if there was a function that did this" was there from the beginning... I don't know how much clearer I can put that. I mean, since there is an `array_pop` and `array_shift` it wouldn't be surprising there is an `array_pop_by_key`, right?

Comment: you can find a list of all array functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php - If there isn't the function you search, you have to create your own custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$a = [
'first' => '1st',
'second' => '2nd',
'third' => '3rd'
];

pull_by_key( $a, 'second' );
function pull_by_key( &$array, $key ){
   $retval = $array[$key];
   unset( $array[$key] );
   return $retval;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($a); die;
```

Comment: dude, that doesn't make sense... $a is already the required way, a print_r( $a ) would show that. No need to put that in a newArray.

Comment: then what is your requirement ?

Comment: "I can shift an item from an array by using array_pop or array_shift, but this works for the beginning or the ending of a string. I'm looking to pull an item from an array by it's key".. the function does that, I was wondering if there was a single command for that already...

Answer (score 0):

Define a temporary array `$tempArray` and push the pulled items inside `$tempArray`:

```
<?php

$a = [
  'first' => '1st',
  'second' => '2nd',
  'third' => '3rd'
];

echo pull_by_key( $a, 'second' );

function pull_by_key( &$array, $key ){
   $tempArray = [];
   $tempArray[$key] = $array[$key];
   unset( $array[$key] );
   return $tempArray[$key];
}
```

Comment: Milan, thanks, but to be clear: the function in my example works fine, and it doesn't have to duplicate an array either, I am just wondering if there is a command for this since there is one to pull an item from the beginning or the end of an array (array_pop and array_shift)

Comment: Well, if you are unsetting it than there is no way to get that value, post the execution of `unset` unless you store in some variable. IMO, I don't think there is any in-built function that can help you achieve your requirement.

Comment: I think you're right... there's no single version. I would prefer to 'duplicate' a single item rather than duplicating a whole array though. But like I said: you're right... there's no single command... I'll put it in as a feature request :)

Comment: Yes, a feature request would be good. And I m not duplicating an entire array but just that key-value and every-time this function is called, the array is emptied :) So its as good as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what php's `array_splice()` does.  I just needed to do a search for the key's offset first.  To prevent any errors caused by trying to access a non-existent element, a condition statemeent was necessary.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/732a761202788582e176f7c7e5d7a9947f686fe4))

```
$a = [
  'first' => '1st',
  'second' => '2nd',
  'third' => '3rd'
];
$find_key='second';
if(($offset=array_search($find_key,array_keys($a)))!==false){
    $pulled=array_splice($a,$offset,1);
    var_export($pulled);
    echo "\n";
    var_export($a);
}else{
    echo "$find_key not found";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'second' => '2nd',
)
array (
  'first' => '1st',
  'third' => '3rd',
)
```